# UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification filter notifications

Tags: ios, nsnotificationcenter

I registered my main view controller for listening to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` because I want to display a `UIAlertView` each time the user enters my app :

```
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];
```

It's working like a charm, my only problem is if my app gets interrupted (by an `UIAletView`, such as a calendar event, or a popup asking for picture access confirmation), the notification gets called once the alert view's dismissed.

Any idea on how  to detect ONLY when my app comes back from background mode ?

Comment: You can make a method in the Appdelegate and call every time when you needed,other solution maintain some tag while calling that some method.

Comment: The problem is not really where to call the method, it's how to get notified ONLY when the apps comes back from background, not when it's interrupted by a system alert view. Maybe I didn't understand your comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use `AppDelegate` method,

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
 //do whatever you want when app comes from background to foreground
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but there is a UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification. Works like this:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                selector:@selector(myMethod)
                                    name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
                                        object:nil];
```

Best regards,

Gabriel Tomitsuka

Answer (score 0):

Check state *(active/background)* of your application by following code:

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
{

        /// your stuff of code:
}
```

Above code might be useful in your case:

Comment: I wrapped the method called by the notification with the code above, and it didn't work. I tried with the popup asking for the right for accessing the photo library. After hitting "Ok", the method gets called, and the state is `UIApplicationStateActive`, so my `UIAlertView` is displayed (and as my application does not come from background, I don't want to display the popup there). Thanks anyway.